# Switching EBS volume type for ElasticSearch cluster from Magnetic to SSD

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch cluster running on AWS which was started with Magnetic EBS volume. 
Now due to increased load on the disk, I want to switch to SSD volume. 
If I directly use the feature to "Configure Cluster" form the UI and switch volume type from Magnetic to GP-SSD. What is the risk of losing the existing data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no risk of loosing data.Basically for administrative operations  like scaling nodes,AWS creates the snapshots of the cluster and launch with the new configuration and map it to our endpoint(The user dont know the internal process).Even though they say zero downtime for cluster scaling,there have been experiences for us like the cluster went to red state for small amount of time when we scaled(There is no data loss).So its best to do the administrative activities when the cluster has very less load and user activity.

Regarding scaling the storage there no risk of data loss.If you are much concerned about you data take a snapshot of the cluster [manually](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/faqs/).AWS automatically take care of all the backups.For answering your question authoritatively, please refer to the aws elasticsearch service [faq](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/faqs/)